# How to resolve FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists?

Tags: python, excel

This error has been asked multiple times in this forum and I tried possible solution but I could not resolve the issue. It does rename the file successfully but still annoying because it gives the same error message. Appreciate your input/help on this. Thank you very much.

Error:

```
    os.rename("Master.xlsx", "Old_Master.xlsx")
    FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Master.xlsx' -> 'Old_Master.xlsx'
```

Code:

```
os.chdir("C:/Path")

for file in os.listdir():
if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
    if os.path.exists("Master.xlsx"):
        os.rename("Master.xlsx", "Old_Master.xlsx")
    os.rename(file, "Master.xlsx")
```

I got this code from someone here, the answer was deleted. Thanks

Comment: Does a file with name `Master.xlsx` already exist in the directory? If yes, then you cannot rename to the same name.

Comment: How can you be surprised by this?  You're  trying to rename several files into a single name.  That's NEVER going to work.  What are you expecting here?

Comment: @amanb there is no Master.xlsx exist on the directory only until a file with a different filename change to Master.xlsx. Thanks

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, thank you for the comments. I have edited the question and posted a script suggested by someone here and got deleted. It works but still showing that error message. Thanks.

Comment: If you only want to convert one file, then WHY ON EARTH are you doing `for file in os.listdir()`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, thank you for the advice and I'm sorry if I somehow upset you with my questions. I am still learning and I appreciate your help and patience. When I remove for file in os.listdir(), the error message disappear but the file is never renamed.

Comment: You are nearly there.  You just need `if os.path.exists("Old_Master.xlsx"):` / `os.remove("Old_Master.xlsx")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to rename all excel file to the same name, that can not be done. instead try to rename files with some change in names like this.

```
for count, file in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        os.rename(file, f"Master{count}.xlsx")
```